# Retrieving Google Reader subscription list in iOS app

Tags: iphone, google-reader

I need to retrieve Google Reader subscription list for a user in a iPhone app. I understand that there is no official API available, and I have kinda exhausted Google search already. Out of various options, the closest I have found is [[[Using JSON Framework on iPhone - HELP!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836445/using-json-framework-on-iphone-help/4029277#4029277)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836445/using-json-framework-on-iphone-help/4029277#4029277)], can anyone share more details - sample code etc.

@WeNeedAnswers> Yes, the OPML format is what I am looking at. But I need to retrieve that directly from my iPhone app.

Comment: I don't know about an API, I know you can download an OPML file with all the subscriptions. The OPML file is an xml file. I'm not an iphone developer, but if I was doing it in c# I would try doing it (if there was no API) using http response request, faking log in etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing an Objective-C wrapper for iOS based apps using GoogleReader API.
The project, inspired by Pyrfeed, is available at https://github.com/zimok/GoogleReaderAPI-iOS

Note that is an ALPHA, and I'm doing an hard refactoring to make it work Asynchronous and using a delegate protocol.

For now there are some base API methods available. Take a look.